# Black eyed children movie

Tags: story-identification, movie

I'm trying to find a movie from a single scene. There are some children with their eyes completely painted around in black moving like zombies and asking for their moms.

I know it is NOT The Village of the Damned.

Comment: Any idea on the time frame you watched it, and if it was old then?

Comment: Are you sure it wasn't TV? Sounds like the Doctor Who episode "The Empty Child"

Comment: There were multiple versions of village of the damned.

Comment: Try looking up "The Children" from 1980. I don't remember if their eyes were black, but their fingernails were. They went around convincing adults to hug them and then killing them using toxic corrosive gas.

Comment: It was not any of the versions of Village of the Damned. These boys had brilliant eyes. It is not Doctor Who's Empty Child: that one had a mask, not black painting around eyes. "The Children" may be the correct one. Please make it an answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This may be "The Children" from 1980. In a small town, a school bus full of children is exposed to a yellow gas near the local nuclear plant, and the children turn into zombie-like killers. The children proceed to invade the town, hugging adults and killing them via the same corrosive yellow gas they were exposed to earlier.

Here's the trailer (or [click here](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NusR2Syokag) to watch it on YouTube):

Also a link to the Wikipedia page: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Children_(1980_film)

Comment: That looks awful.  Is it on netflix?

Comment: Second 22 is what makes the point. Thanks. Accepted.

Comment: @Dason not sure. When searching on YouTube I think I saw one or two that may have been the full movie. Try searching for "The Children 1980" on YouTube and see if it's there.